# Current user returned in incorrect format - Master Page - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a little trouble here. I need to return the current logged on user in the SharePoint. I'm expecting something like `James Ward`, not `i:0#.f|membership|jamesw@gmail.com`

So far this is the code that I used inside the Master Page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = currentUser.get_id();
document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' +     args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

and I used this line of code to show the return value on my Master Page:

```
<span>Welcome to My Page,<span id="userLoginName"></span></span>
```

Unfortunately, `userLoginName` return this: `i:0#.f|membership|jamesw@gmail.com`

How can I return `James Ward` instead of `i:0#.f|membership|jamesw@gmail.com` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some alternative, I came with this solution:

```
<script src="../../Style%20Library/MyJsFolder/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
< script type = "text/javascript" >
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" +
userid + ")";
var requestHeaders = {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
};
$.ajax({
url: requestUri,
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
headers: requestHeaders,
success: onSuccess,
error: onError
});

function onSuccess(data, request) {
var Logg = data.d;
document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = Logg.Title;
}

function onError(error) {
alert("error");
} < /script>
```

and we can return the display name like this:

`<span id="userLoginName"></span>`

I'm not good in js or sharepoint (i found this solution online and modify it) but I'm sharing this solution so we can refer to this if we have trouble in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `currentUser.get_title()` instead of `currentUser.get_loginName();`.

```
document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
```

Of course it could be a little bit misleading because span has id 'userLoginName' and you are showing user title. Maybe you should consider changing id of the span to 'userTitle'. I can see that you have some another span with this id and you actually set it to currentUser.get_title(). So maybe it is a good idea to swap places for `userLoginName` span and `userTitle` span.

```
<span>Welcome to My Page,<span id="userTitle"></span></span>
```

Comment: this does't work. `currentUser.get_title();` doesn't return any value

Comment: That is odd, it should work. Seems like your Title property is filled correctly because you were able to get it using REST.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SP.User.get_title()` property to retrieve user name, for example:

```
var userName = user.get_title();
```

### How to retrieve current user in SharePoint 2013 via CSOM/REST

**CSOM**

```
function getCurrentUser(success, failure) {
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
   ctx.load(user); 

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(user);
      }, 
      failure
   );
}
```

Usage

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
  getCurrentUser(
    function(user){
     document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = user.get_title();
    },
    function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());     
    });
},'sp.js');
```

**REST**

```
function getCurrentUser(success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentUser",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage

```
getCurrentUser(
  function(user){
     document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = user.Title;
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

Comment: Vadim, can you explain more regarding the `SP.User.get_title()`? Maybe with a sample of code. I'm not good at js :(